# looking for # on a url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a some tab panels on my html page, and each tab has an href telling the tab like this:

```
<li class="list"><a href="#tab6">FAQs / Ajuda</a></li>
```

but I would like to open that #tab6 from another page and make my active tab onload.

Can someone give me a little piece of jquery sample to accomplish this this?

I thought about the href from the another page call something like: http://somelink.com/help.html#tab6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is the url `hash`. You can get the value like, no jQuery needed:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

Answer (score 4):

Give this a shot:

```
<li class="list"><a id="tab6" href="#tab6">FAQs / Ajuda</a></li>
```

---

```
$(function() {
    var hash = window.location.hash || '#tab1';

    // your code setting up your tabs

    $(hash).click();
});
```

Add IDs to the tabs that match the hashes, and add the `$(hash).click();` *after* you've set up the `.click()` handlers for your tabs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  //use location.hash and do whatever you need to activate the tab here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to do, but it sounds like you need to use location.hash.

maybe on page load you can call something like

```
if(location.hash == "#tab6"){
//put the code to set your tabs here
}
```